# Comparing strings in Kotlin by custom ordering defined in another list

Tags: list, sorting, kotlin, comparison

I have a list of Accounts:

```
data class Account(
        val currency: String?
)
```

I need to sort the accounts by the currency, but not by the natural (alphabetical) ordering of the strings, which all the tutorials out there have already explained to the death, but by a custom ordering, defined preferably in a list, so I don't have to do some ugly "if-else" chain of some sort. For example, if I used the list

```
listOf("USD", "EUR", "RMB")
```

for the sorting, then accounts with currency "USD" would come first, those with "EUR second", and the ones with "RMB" last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sortedBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) function will work:

```
val sortOrder = listOf("USD", "EUR", "RMB")
val accounts = listOf(Account("EUR"), Account("USD"), Account("RMB"))
val sortedAccounts = accounts.sortedBy { sortOrder.indexOf(it.currency) }
```

Comment: Thanks! I came across this piece of documentation as well, but I didn't know that something like sortOrder existed. I can't actually find anything about sortOrder, even when searching directly for it. All I'm getting are "natural sort order" duds. Huh...

Comment: `sortOrder` is just a random name I choose for the list of currencies. Inside `sortedBy` I use the `indexOf` function with this list to get the index of the currency. The index is then used as the sorting criteria.

Comment: My bad, I copypasted the wrong name, which explains my googling difficulties earlier. I meant sortedBy.